# no such file to load active_record/associations/has_and_belongs_to_many_association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I added the composite_primary_keys gem in my Gemfile. On local environment it runs fine, but on a centos machine it breaks with the following error. Ruby version is 1.9.2p290 and rubygems version is 1.3.7 on both environments. Does anyone know why that could be?

```ruby
bundle exec rake db:create --trace

no such file to load -- active_record/associations/has_and_belongs_to_many_association
/var/tmp/jenkins/gem_cache/myapp/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/var/tmp/jenkins/gem_cache/myapp/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/var/tmp/jenkins/gem_cache/myapp/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/var/tmp/jenkins/gem_cache/myapp/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/var/tmp/jenkins/gem_cache/myapp/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/var/tmp/jenkins/gem_cache/myapp/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/var/tmp/jenkins/gem_cache/myapp/gems/composite_primary_keys-4.1.2/lib/composite_primary_keys.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/opt/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/opt/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/opt/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/opt/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/opt/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/opt/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
```

Comment: Could you add links to gists of your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock?

Comment: can you type bundle list into both environments.  Also try doing bundle clean then bundle install on remote.

Comment: Thanks Lars. [Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/2926554) and [Gemfile.lock](https://gist.github.com/2926555)

Comment: Thanks Michael, i cannot clean the bundle as its a jenkins machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning the shared gems list on the jenkins machine fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The same error can occur when trying to use the composite_primary_keys gem with Active Record 4.1.0:

```
.../vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_record/associations/has_and_belongs_to_many_association (LoadError)
  from .../vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  from .../vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  ...
```

This is because the current release of composite_primary_keys (version 6.0.1 as of 17 April 2014) doesn't include support for Active Record 4.1.0, which apparently removed the file in question.

The problem is fixed in [the `ar_4.1.x` branch of the gem's source code](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys/tree/ar_4.1.x), however. If your project uses Bundler, a solution is to edit its Gemfile and replace the line

```
gem 'composite_primary_keys'
```

with

```
gem 'composite_primary_keys', {
  :git => 'git://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys.git',
  :branch => 'ar_4.1.x'
}
```

then run `bundle install` from your project's root folder.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. That branch doesn't currently support 4.1 final, but I am sure it will soon.

Comment: @Tricon: Yes, I've just realized today support for 4.1 is only preliminary. So perhaps the most _immediate_ solution is to downgrade to Active Record 4.0, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Gemfile:
`gem 'composite_primary_keys', '~> 7.0'`

Comment: What's your reasoning?