# no such file to load active_record/associations/has_and_belongs_to_many_association - composite_primary_keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I faced the issue same as  [no such file to load active_record/associations/has_and_belongs_to_many_association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023167/no-such-file-to-load-active-record-associations-has-and-belongs-to-many-associat/23142066#23142066)?

Tried the solution suggested

The problem is fixed in the ar_4.1.x branch of the gems source code, however. If your   project uses Bundler, a solution is to edit its Gemfile and replace the line

```
`gem composite_primary_keys`
```

with

```
gem composite_primary_keys, {
:git => git://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys.git,
:branch => ar_4.1.x
}`
```

But  I got the below error-

```
$ bundle update
Updating git://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
In Gemfile:
rails (= 4.1.0) ruby depends on
activerecord (= 4.1.0) ruby

composite_primary_keys (>= 0) ruby depends on
activerecord (4.1.0.rc2)`
```

Please advise how to go from here ?

Comment: You'll either need to get the author of CPK to update the gemspec or fork the repo and do it yourself.